# Android spinner remove dropdown vertical extra space / padding

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android app developing as i was creating spinner i noticed a extra space / padding vertically to drop down list of the spinner at the start and end of the drop down.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner sr = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        String[] days = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ar = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.single_row, days);
        sr.setAdapter(ar);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#666666"
    tools:context="com.xxxxx.defaultspinner.MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:background="#898989">

    </Spinner>

</RelativeLayout>
```

single_row.xml

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:background="#214161">

</TextView>
```

[image]

[image]

I set background of all the views to different color so that i can identify the source of the extra space / padding. But the the extra space / padding has white background which none of the view has.

**Note** this is not because of the **spinnerMode="dialog"** option. this behavior is also happens when **spinnerMode="dropdown"**. How can i remove this space ? or i am doing something wrong ?

Comment: did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 6):

You just need to override the getDropDownView method in the adapter.

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    parent.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your `TextView`

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

it will remove the `TextView` extra top and bottom padding

Comment: No the extra space / padding is not from the textview because background color of textview is #214161 where as extra space/padding background is #FFFFFF. I also tested your answer still the same result